Problems with NotificationAndroidCrontab schedule with Awesome_notification in flutter
The problem i have is this error .
Exception has occurred.
PlatformException (PlatformException(INVALID_ARGUMENTS, Schedule cron expression is invalid, arguments.invalid.crontabExpression, null))
!D/*
This happents only when i m  trying to specify the days on crontabExpression.
Example:
Future<void> customNotification({
  required int idNotification,
  required int idMedicine,
  required int listLenght,
  required String groupKey,
  required DateTime endingDate,
  required DateTime startDate,
  required String myCron,
  required String medicareName,
  required int numberOfMedicine,
  required String medicineType,
}) async {
  log('my id is $idNotification , my medicine id is $idMedicine, myCron is $myCron   ,my starting date is ${startDate.toIso8601String()} my date is ending date ${endingDate.toIso8601String()} ');//debug

  await AwesomeNotifications().createNotification(
    content: NotificationContent(
      notificationLayout: NotificationLayout.BigPicture,
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
      id: idNotification,
      groupKey: groupKey,
      color: Colors.lightBlue,
      channelKey: 'medicine_channel',
      actionType: ActionType.Default,
      title: 'Hi, it\'s time for your medication',
      body:'Take your medication named $medicareName at quantity \n $numberOfMedicine $medicineType.$idNotification',//debug 
      autoDismissible: true,
      payload: {'$idMedicine': '$listLenght'},
    ),
    schedule: NotificationAndroidCrontab(
        allowWhileIdle: true,
        expirationDateTime: endingDate,
        initialDateTime: startDate,
        crontabExpression: myCron,
        
        preciseAlarm: true),
    actionButtons: <NotificationActionButton>[
      NotificationActionButton(
          color: Colors.blue,
          key: 'take',
          label: 'take',
          actionType: ActionType.SilentAction),
      NotificationActionButton(
          isDangerousOption: true,
          color: Colors.red,
          key: 'cancel',
          label: 'cancel',
          actionType: ActionType.SilentAction),
    ],
  );
}

If i put inside the myCron value something like 0 44 2 * * ? *
it works fine but if i do something like :
  44 2 * * 1,2,5
  0 44 2 * * 1,2,5
  ? 44 2 * * 1,2,5
  ? 44 2 * * MON,TUE,FRI
  44 2 * * MON,TUE,FRI
  ? 44 2 * * 1,2,5 *
  0 44 2 * * 1,2,5 ? (and more)

it throws that error(at the start).
What i want is to make a cron that for every Monday,Saturday or at least every Monday at current time the notification to happen. As it shown above ,i have try many ways to do it yet nothing works .
Is there a way to solve this problem  ?
Thank you for your time.
